# custom TableViewCell out of order?

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

ive been having a lot of issues with my tableview getting out of order or losing a custom image in the tableview cell. I have been doing a lot of research and found a few helpful things on it but none seem to resolve my issue. It seems to be an issue with the reuse cell. I also have an if statement to change an images background on the custom cell depending on what button you press. Any help would be awesome thanks.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! expenseTableViewCell

    let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]
    cell.expenseName.text = expenses[indexPath.row].ename
    cell.expenseCost.text = "$" + expenses[indexPath.row].ecost!
    cell.expenseDue.text = expenses[indexPath.row].edue

    //CHANGE BACKGROUND VIEW COLOR
    if expense.picture == "1"{

        cell.picture.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 116/255, blue: 115/255, alpha:1)
    }

    if expense.picture == "2"{

        cell.picture.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 192/255, blue: 255/255, alpha:1)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking to me, but It might help to override `prepareForReuse` in your `expenseTableViewCell` (please start class names with capital letters) and set the backgroundColor to white there.

Comment: thanks dude its a little confusing. My custom tableview cell is out of order I have a few custom labels and a custom image in the cell. I did add this to my expenseTableViewCell and still not luck.                     override func prepareForReuse() {
        expenseDue.text = ""
        expenseName.text = ""
        expenseCost.text = ""
        picture.image = nil
    }

Comment: Then I'd say that `expenses` is not "settled" each time you call it? Could you print it each time? Is it reorder in the meanwhile?

Comment: do you have button on each cell? when it clicked will change expense.picture value?

Comment: if you tap a button on a separate view it segues over to tell it what to set the expense.picture value

Comment: can you share code when button tapped?

Comment: @IBAction func Send(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let userInput = Field.text
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Expense", sender: userInput)

    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if expense.picture == "1"{

    cell.picture.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 116/255, blue: 115/255, alpha:1)
} else if expense.picture == "2"{

    cell.picture.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 192/255, blue: 255/255, alpha:1)
}
```

Because you are reusing cells, you can't have if statements the way you are writing them. You have to use else if otherwise the cells that stay in memory mess things up.

Comment: Would this still work if there are 12 different color options?

Comment: Yes it will as long as you use `expense.picture == "3"` and so on until 12.

Comment: Awesome thank you I’ll try it out when I get a chance I’ll comment if it’s able to work for me. Thank you!

Comment: when using tableview, you generally have to be more explicit when defining cases using an if statement. You shouldn't do things like `if test==true {} else {}` instead you should explicitly write out the cases like this `if test==true {} else if test==false {}`

Comment: you also also add a default case using `else{ cell.picture.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30/255, green: 192/255, blue: 255/255, alpha:1) }` so in the case that none of them are true it will default to a value

Comment: That worked great for my images disappearing but still having my tableview cells going out of order.. any thoughts?

Comment: awesome. is your class for expenses a value type or a reference type? is it declared as a struct or class? try using a struct instead of a class if you are editing, deleting and adding a bunch of things to your class. but generally this shouldn't cause an issue. in order to really diagnose the issue, you would have to share more code. the one thing I suggest is using ``expenses.ename` instead of this `expenses[indexPath.row].ename`. You have already declared this `let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]` so there is no need to redo it every time you use an instance of expenses